# Oracle APEX 5.0: Labels on Line Charts

Tags: flot, oracle-apex-5, anychart

I'm using Oracle APEX 5.0 and I want to create some line charts in my application. The default flash charts don't look very nice, so I tried importing some plugins of Flot Line Chart and D3 Line Chart from the Sample Charts dashboard. They look much better however the attributes don't have an option to display the labels. The only option is via a Tooltip. Is it possible to display labels on the lines instead?

The line chart example without any labels:

[image]

Expected output is the data points on the line would show the data labels as well.

EDIT:

[This](https://pastebin.com/8JJ9igW0) is the D3 Line chart plugin i'm using.

I'm just using the sample chart that's provided and the SQL is simply

```
SELECT
    pricing_date,
    closing_val,
    stock_code
FROM
    EBA_DEMO_CHART_STOCKS
```

The available attributes of the chart are:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the documentation, please check this url, you will find some good examples

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/5841/index-en.html

Comment: Hi, I couldn't quite figure out much from that. I understand I can give my chart a Static ID and then use that static ID to modify its attributes using inline CSS. How do I know what the variable name for the label would be so I can set it in the below code?

`<circle class="a-D3LineChart-pointContainer-dot u-Color-2-BG--fill u-Color-2-BG--br" r="2.5" cx="0" cy="24.62900157782532" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="1" tabindex="-1"></circle>`

Comment: The plugin is using JET Charts. You can modify the properties thru javascript, take a look in this example. https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=lineChart&demo=dataLabels

Comment: I don't have APEX 5 but I have 19, if you can give an example of your chart I can help you to render the labels

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by example of chart. I've added the details of the plugin I use and the attributes it has. Would that help or do you any need other details? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Enrique, did you get a chance to look at this? Should I be providing any other information?